# How to fix powershell `Import-Module DnsClient` failure 'Cannot process Cmdlet Definition XML'

Tags: powershell

I seldom use PowerShell but I wanted to use `Set-DnsClientServerAddress`. Running it directly tells me I need to import module DnsClient. When I run `Import-Module DnsClient` I get the output below. What's going on? I certainly haven't been messing with these windows files. I'm running PS v4 on Windows 8.

```
PS C:\> Import-Module DnsClient
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsClient.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'TypesToProcess' from path
'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsCmdlets.Types.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'TypesToProcess' from path
'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsConfig.Types.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'TypesToProcess' from path
'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsClientPSProvider.Types.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path
'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsCmdlets.Format.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path
'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsConfig.Format.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path
'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\DnsClientPSProvider.Format.ps1xml'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\dnslookup.dll'.
VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Resolve-DnsName'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\MSFT_DnsClient.cdxml'.
Import-Module : Cannot process Cmdlet Definition XML for the following file:
C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DnsClient\MSFT_DnsClient.cdxml. At line:374 char:13
+             $__cmdletization_exceptionHasBeenThrown = $true
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:375 char:13
+             throw
+             ~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:380 char:9
+         $__cmdletization_exceptionHasBeenThrown = $false
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:383 char:13
+             __cmdletization_BindCommonParameters $__cmdletization_objectModelWra ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:384 char:13
+             $__cmdletization_objectModelWrapper.BeginProcessing()
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:388 char:13
+             $__cmdletization_exceptionHasBeenThrown = $true
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:389 char:13
+             throw
+             ~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:381 char:9
+         try
+         ~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:399 char:5
+     $__cmdletization_queryBuilder = $__cmdletization_objectModelWrapper.GetQuery ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
At line:400 char:66
+     if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('InterfaceIndex') -and (@('ByName') -cont ...
+                                                                  ~~~~~~~~
Executable script code found in signature block.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module DnsClient
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XmlException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

PS C:\>
```